# Graduating Quantitative Finance (please don't move it to meta immidiately)

Tags: general

Seeing how very few actually read the Quant Finance meta I intentionally post it here on the main site.

**To the more powerful admins:** 
could you leave it here for a day or two and move it to meta afterwards? (please)

On Area51 I was told to [post the question on Meta](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1396/when-are-we-going-to-graduate) - perhaps we can raise awareness of the Quant SE staff via some views or votes. I must admit I have no idea whome to ask to get genuin ***feedack on what the site is lacking from the perspektive of the SE-Staff***.

Comment: Could you please do some spell checking of the linked question? :) Anyway I personally think it would demotivate us, I'd give it a few more months of spicy beta...

Comment: sry - English is not my native language - I did write it in MS Word to decrease the amount of typos and spelling errors. Okey you make a valid agrument but I still wanted the community to know that I care and that graduating is still an option :)

Comment: @vonjd thanks for the upvote - eventhough I don't think I deserved one - seeing how I did not contribute anything of professional/subject relevant value. Still, very pleasant to know that there are people out there who feel the same :)

Comment: The question got closed on Area51 :-(

Comment: I posted it on meta for the SE-admins to see

Comment: IMHO, the site has a very low popularity compared to Wilmott.com which has a huge and dominant quant finance audience and reach. Also, quant finance is an area with too many niche sub-areas little related to each other - for instance derivatives (& risk), quant equity research, quant macro. very few people will answer any practitioner-level quant equity or quant macro questions due to IP issues - resulting in mostly college kids asking and a few academics/ post-docs/PhD kids answering. lastly, SE is very strict as per its posting standards - all silly/vanilla posts will happen on wilmott.com

Comment: @uday I know that Wilmott is known better but the quality of the answers is often horrible. In a time when I was still unaware of Quant Finance SE I browsed a couple of posts. Often you will end up reading one page of gibberish before arriving a more or less useful answer to the question at hand.

Comment: I am also aware that most practicioners will discuss the more subtle points of their trade within the institution they are working for or within their own private network. All the same Quant SE can cater to people who are self-teaching themselves quant finance or to private trades interest in the material. Also Some out of the box ideas could be discussed here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't serve any purpose here any more as it's hardly visible and can't be migrated. BTW Meta has some discussion on this topic now.